# Using 'sed' command in python to replace a value of a key in the config file

Tags: python

I need to provide a value that comes from a string variable (e.g "abc/def/ghi" directory path that contains the forward slash '/') as the new value of a key in the config file through my python script.

I am using this code below

```
cmd = 'sed -i -e "/dir            =/ s/= .*/= /{new_value}/" {dst_file}'.format(new_value=filepath,dst_file=config_filename)
os.system(cmd)

But I am getting this error
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
256
(Pdb)
```

How can I fix it?  I think the forward slash in the directory path(new value for the key) is causing the problem.

Comment: The syntax of the `s` command is `s/<pattern>/<replacement>/<flags>`. It looks like you have too many `/` in your expression, because you have `{new_value}` where the flags should go.

Comment: The slash `/` before `{new_value}`  should be removed or, if is meant to be there, escaped like this `\/`